# Easier way to see your suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, editing, review, suggested-edits

Is there an easier way to see your suggested edits, specifically those which are rejected?

You get a '+2' reputation notification for approved edits but you're not notified when an edit is declined (which is probably more important). I ask this because I noticed that the decline option has several different 'reasons', which may prove to be constructive to the editor (me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see your suggested edits under your activity in your profile. In your case:

- https://askubuntu.com/users/176889/minerz029?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Unfortunately it isn't indicated which were accepted and rejected there but you can go through each and see what its outcome was (along with the reject message).

Comment: I was looking for a page similar to your 'raised flags' page which shows the reason for flagging (edit summary) and the outcome: active, helpful or declined. This is helpful, though